# Create a datetime column with default current time in sqlite

Tags: datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a sqlite data object say "Ticket".
I have some column fields in it which are populated by date received from server.

I want to add a datetime column which has to set its value to default current date time whenever record is created.

```
public class Ticket : BaseNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int MobileID { get; set; }
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    //new column to be added with default datetime
    public DateTime test

}
```

Comment: Look into triggers to let the database handle this https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public DateTime test { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

This will only work if exactly as above. If you write custom `get` and `set` then I would think you can set the default for the backing field, e.g.:

```
DateTime _time = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime Time { 
    get{
        return _time;
    } 
    set {
        if (_time != value) {
            _time = value;

        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
( 
     MobileID BIGINT (14) NOT NULL, 
     TicketID BIGINT(14) NOT NULL, 
     date     DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
     PRIMARY KEY (MobileID, TicketID ) 
);
```